# ReactNative 0.71.4 error on build android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, build

CMake Warning at C:/Users/ErykTavares/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
CMake's built-in compiler identification.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Users/ErykTavares/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
.cxx/Debug/2f544m1t/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901-dirty/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)

ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 24s

```
at makeError (D:\backup\paradas_da_area_de_trabalho\GitHub\Freelancer\projetos bird\birdie-app\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)      
at D:\backup\paradas_da_area_de_trabalho\GitHub\Freelancer\projetos bird\birdie-app\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\backup\paradas_da_area_de_trabalho\GitHub\Freelancer\projetos bird\birdie-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\backup\paradas_da_area_de_trabalho\GitHub\Freelancer\projetos bird\birdie-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

..............................................................................................................

Comment: any luck? I am also facing the same issue.